# Is there any string.Contains or related method

Tags: c#, string

I am writing a code to if characters from 1 string are present in another string. I used string.Contains but its not solving my case

```
string str = "abc";
string str2 = "ac";

if(str.Contains(str2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
```

I want result to be true. but its not returning true

Comment: It's right that this is false, becaus ac is not contains in abc. That means their not in this order.

Comment: You can use Regex if you don't want to use string.Contains();

Comment: you want to check full string or you want to vheck character ?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to check if *any* of the characters are present in the string, or if *all* the characters are present?

Comment: I want to check if all characters of str2 are present in str

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
string str = "abc";
string str2 = "ac";

bool containsAll = !str2.Except(str).Any();
```

because

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a code to if characters from 1 string are present in another string.

I guess you want to check: " if [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) characters from 1 string are present in another string."

```
string str = "abc";
string str2 = "ac";

Console.WriteLine(str2.All(x => str.Contains(x)));
```